# Reading double Numbers from a text file which contains string and number mixed

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file which contains Numbers and Texts. and I'm trying to read all numbers as double and put them in a one dimension double array.

In the file , some lines begin with **Space**. also some lines contain Two or Three numbers after each other.
The file is creating from another app which i don't want to change its output format.

The data in the file is like blow and some lines begin with some space :

```
 110        ! R1
123.000753   ! Radian per s as R2
  600.0451  65     ! j/kg
 12000         ! 4 Number of iteration
 87.619    ! (min 20 and max 1000)
```

My code so far is :

```
 char[] splits = { ' ', '!' };
 var array = File.ReadAllLines(@"myfile.dat")
.SelectMany(linee => linee.Split(splits))
.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.ToString()))
.Select(n =>
 {
  double doub;
  bool suc = double.TryParse(n, out  doub);
  return new { doub, suc };
 }).Where( values=>values.suc).ToArray();
```

The problem is that my code also read numbers after `!` in the descriptions like **line 4 and line 5**.

Array have to be like this :

> 110 , 123.000735 , 6000.0451 , 65 , 120000 , 87.619

But in my code is like this  :

> 110 , 123.000735 , 6000.0451 , 65 , 120000 , 4 , 87.619 , 20 , 1000

Comment: You can't split on both spaces and exclamation mark in one split; and get the desired results.

Comment: Is there always going to be a `!` on each line?

Comment: @DourHighArch yes it has ! always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a general formula when given only a single example, but the following will work for your example:

```
return File.ReadLines(@"myfile.dat")
    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('!')).Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .SelectMany(s => s)
    .Select(s => Double.Parse(s));
```

Comment: this: Length cannot be less than zero.
i also removed all null lines and now all lines contains !

Comment: it worked ! thank you so much.
it seems my last line was still null. i removed it and it now working.
is there anyway it doen't read null lines?

Comment: Check my edit. Also, it is not clear if you wanted a string with commas, or an array of doubles; please clarify.

Comment: Added `Double.Parse`. If there can be non-doubles in the list, put a `.Where(s => Double.TryParse(s))`  before the last `.Select`. Also, this returns an `IEnumerable<Double>`, which you should probably be using not an array. If you really do need an array add `.ToArray()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as following.

```
var lines = str.Split(new []{"!",Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Where(x=> x.Split(new []{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).All(c=>double.TryParse(c, out _))).
               SelectMany(x=> x.Split(new []{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(c=>double.Parse(c)));
```

Comment: thank for answer i will try it in my code and will say result :)

Comment: If you don't need the file contents as a whole, I would read it as an array of lines. It would save the allocation of a potential large array just for splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution using regular expressions:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(\s*(?<v>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*)+\!.*$");

var query = from line in lines
            let match = regex.Match(line)
            where match.Success
            from @group in match.Groups.Cast<Group>()
            where @group.Name == "v"
            select double.Parse(@group.Value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```